# How to set different heights on panels from an accordion?

Tags: javafx-2, javafx, accordion, fxml, scene

is there a way to have panels with different heights in an accordion in JavaFX? I would like to know how to do it. I've googled it but I haven't found what I need.

Comment: i am not getting exactly getting what you say , if you want to set all panes different sizes at initial time then i give answer below..if its somethings else tell me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do this with `setPrefHeight` of pane....

try this.

```
pane.setPrefHeight(400);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried this before but it didn't work, I figure out it had something to do with the changes I made on the stylesheet

Comment: @Andre its at inital time and its perfectly...if you want to set it some change then you can use event...if you have some more issue tell me in some details

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Accordion;
import javafx.scene.control.TitledPane;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TitledPaneSample extends Application
{
final String[]     imageNames = new String[]{
    "Apples", "Flowers", "Leaves"};
final Image[]      images     = new Image[imageNames.length];
final ImageView[]  pics       = new ImageView[imageNames.length];
final TitledPane[] tps        = new TitledPane[imageNames.length];

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    launch(args);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage stage)
{
    stage.setTitle("TitledPane");
    Scene scene = new Scene(new Group(), 380, 380);
    scene.setFill(Color.GHOSTWHITE);

    final Accordion accordion = new Accordion();

    for (int i = 0; i < imageNames.length; i++)
    {
        images[i] = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream(imageNames[i]
            + ".jpg"));
        pics[i] = new ImageView(images[i]);
        tps[i] = new TitledPane(imageNames[i], pics[i]);
        tps[i].setMinHeight(i * 100);
    }
    accordion.getPanes().addAll(tps);
    accordion.setExpandedPane(tps[0]);

    Group root = (Group) scene.getRoot();
    root.getChildren().add(accordion);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}
}
```

All you need in addition to the above code is to have the three files placed at the correct location.